# help-need to determine that this induced map is the zero map

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f : S^3 \rightarrow S^3$ have the property $f(x) = f(-x)$ for every $x \in S^3$. Show that $f_{*} : H_{3}S^3 \rightarrow H_{3}S^3$ is the zero map.

Comment: Possible way to do this: show that $f$ is not surjective. Then it must be homotopic to a constant map and hence trivial on homology.

Comment: Any such map $S^n\to S^n$ (called an *even map*) has even degree, and its degree is *zero* when $n$ is even. But when $n$ is odd you can construct such a map with any even degree.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is true.
Consider the following map: $\mathbb{R}P^3 \to \mathbb{R}P^3/\mathbb{R}P^2 \cong S^3$ which collapses the subcomplex $\mathbb{R}P^2$ to a point.
You can precompose this with the projection $S^3 \to \mathbb{R}P^3$ to obtain a map $S^3 \to S^3$ having the property you want.
This map has degree $2$.

In general, maps of the sort you describe are bijective to maps from $\mathbb{R}P^3 \to S^3$.
But it is a fact that $$\lbrack \mathbb{R}P^3, S^3 \rbrack \cong H^3(\mathbb{R}P^3;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}.$$

More or less, this is how I constructed a counterexample to your question.